# Counting events from a GRIB raster

Tags: python, gdal, grib

I have been attempting to find a solution to the problem of limited access to GRIB_API(on Windows) through using GDAL in Python.

The main thing I want to achieve is to be able to set some conditions, then iterate through folder(s) for a given time period and produce a raster that would represent the amount of times the conditions were met in a format that is easily handeled by most GIS software, such as GeoTIFF.

I have written up two blocks of code either of wich should do this for me, but I at best get a blank raster. I assume it is either a flush to disk problem or I am missing something to translate integers into GeoTIFF.

> This is one version:
>
> ```
> import gdal
> import numpy
>
>
> src_ds = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-0000.grb')
> format = "GTiff"
> driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
> dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy('01012014.tif', src_ds, 0)
>
>
> def krog(baza,novi):  
>   x = 0
>   while x < 25:
>       baza = gdal.Open('01012014.tif')
>       if x < 10:
>           novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
>           if novi > 1 and novi < 5:
>               baza = baza + 1
>           else:
>               baza = baza + 0
>
>       elif x > 10:
>           novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
>           if novi > 1 and novi < 5:
>               baza = baza + 1
>           else:
>               baza = baza + 0
>       x += 1  
> dst_ds = None
> src_ds = None
> ```
>
> This is the other:
>
> ```
> import gdal
> import numpy
>
> dst_ds = driver.Create('01012014.tif', 400, 300, 1, gdal.GDT_CInt32)
> dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([4468800, 30, 0, 1223500, 0, -30])
>
> srs = osr.SpatialReference()
> srs.SetUTM(11,1)
> srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('LCC')
> dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
>
> raster = numpy.zeros((400, 300), dtype=numpy.uint8)
> dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
>
>
> def krog(baza,novi):  
>   x = 0
>   while x < 25:
>       baza = gdal.Open('01012014.tif')
>       if x < 10:
>           novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
>           if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
>               baza = baza + 1
>           else:
>               baza = baza + 0
>
>       elif x > 10:
>           novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
>           if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
>               baza = baza + 1
>           else:
>               baza = baza + 0
>       x += 1  
> dst_ds = None
> ```

GRIB files have 4 bands (Temperature, Humidity, u and v values) and are provided for every full hour in a day (most of the time).

EDIT: Following advice I adopted the second version like this:

```
import gdal
import numpy
import osr

ime_rez = str(input("Poimenuj datoteko z rezultati:") + ".tif")
#User can provide a name for the output picture
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
dst_ds = driver.Create(ime_rez, 400, 300, 1, gdal.GDT_CInt32)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([4468800, 30, 0, 1223500, 0, -30])

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetUTM(11,1)
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('LCC')
dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

raster = numpy.zeros((400, 300), dtype=numpy.uint8)


def krog(baza,novi):    
    x = 0
    while x < 25:
        baza = gdal.Open(ime_rez)
        if x < 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
            #This should open the next file in line
            if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0

        elif x > 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
            if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0
        x += 1 
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)      
dst_ds = None
```

This now results in a "ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge". I believe this is a problem because the cell size in .grb files is 1000 m, but I have yet to find a way to manually set it in the newly created .tif.

Comment: Two issues that I can spot at first glance: 1st script - `CreateCopy` creates a copy of a dataset - you are trying to change the driver and format as well. 2nd script - you are creating an image filled with zeros and write it to disk after your processing loop. You would need to do the processing and afterwards use `WriteArray` followed by closing the dataset.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I should first write an array of 0s to disk then reopen it for processing and finish by writing all to disk again?

Comment: Ideally you would create an array of 0s (in memory), read your GRIB files and do the manipulations and afterwards write to disk. i.e. in the second script move `WriteArray` to the end just before `dst_ds=None`

Comment: I tried that and I get an error with dst_ds = driver.Create that tells me: name 'driver' is not defined. Do I need to define it (like driver = 'GeoTIFF')? Or is there something elese I should do?

Comment: That's because the second script is missing the driver invocation - you can see how that works in the 1st script.

Comment: Now I seem to be having a problem with raster size, since I get a "ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge". Is there a way to perscribe the cell size (to 1000 m in my case) or do I have to make both rasters(tif and grib) use the same projection and transformation? The GDAL API Tutorial is not as helpfull as I'd like.