# ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge Python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, grib

I have been working on this iterator that would count instances where data conformed to a set of conditions over a number of rasters. I had people help me with other aspects of this script ([Counting events from a GRIB raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247962/counting-events-from-a-grib-raster)), but now I have hit an error where the return is "ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge", Which I can't seem to be able to work arround. The code is provided bellow. It requires the user to input the path to folder and provide a name for the output GeoTIFF raster. Files read are GRIB.

```
import gdal
import numpy
import osr
import os

del_mapa = str(input('Vpiši pot do datotek v obliki "C:\\Mapa1\\Mapa2\\...\\Zadnja mapa": '))
os.chdir(del_mapa)

pix_vel = 1000
#Defines pixel size
ime_rez = str(input("Poimenuj datoteko z rezultati: ") + ".tif")
#User can provide a name for the output picture
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

vir_mere = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-0100.grb')
trans = vir_mere.GetGeoTransform()
geotrans0 = trans[0]
geotrans1 = trans[1]
geotrans3 = trans[3]
geotrans5 = trans[5]
#Extracts transformation data from one of the GRIBs
dst_ds = driver.Create(ime_rez, 401, 301, 1, gdal.GDT_CInt32)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([geotrans0, geotrans1, 0, geotrans3, 0, geotrans5])
#and pastes it directly into the newly created GeoTIFF
projInfo = vir_mere.GetProjection()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(vir_mere.GetProjectionRef())

dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

raster = numpy.zeros((401, 301), dtype=numpy.uint8)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)

def krog(baza,novi):    
    x = 0
    while x < 25:
        baza = gdal.Open(ime_rez)
        if x < 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
            #This should open the next file in line
            if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0

        elif x > 10:
            # novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
            if novi > 15 and novi < 25:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0
        x += 1 
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(baza)        
dst_ds = None
```

Comment: Try: `raster = numpy.zeros((301, 401), dtype=numpy.uint8)`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error, but now I can only get a blank raster out of the program and I know that it should produce some hits (there should be more than 0 everywhere) and I tried different conditions...

Comment: What is your dataset raster: raster or baza? I cannot see how baza dataset values  were changed for obtaining a new raster.

Comment: raster is the one that is filled with numpy zeroes, baza is defined right after the while x < 25: line.

Comment: I'll take a look later.

Comment: I have made a small mistake in the elif section, there really should not be a # befor novi = gdal.Open(...

Comment: I hate to bother you, but have you noticed anything that might be of help here? I can still only get a blank raster full of zeroes out of it and I have changed some things...

Answer (score 2):

As @xunilk indicated in a comment. This `ValueError` is due to a mix up of columns and rows. You were trying to write a 401x301 array into a 301x401 raster.

Your 2nd issue is that you are trying to write an array of `numpy.uint8` into a raster of `gdal.GDT_CInt32`. The resulting image will be no good; often resulting in an all-black raster.

You should use `numpy.int32` to match `gdal.GDT_CInt32` or else use one of the other gdal data types:

```
 'GDT_Byte', 'GDT_CFloat32', 'GDT_CFloat64', 'GDT_CInt16', 'GDT_CInt32', 'GDT_Float32', 'GDT_Float64', 'GDT_Int16', 'GDT_Int32', 'GDT_TypeCount', 'GDT_UInt16', 'GDT_UInt32'
```