# GDAL program produces only zeroes, regardless

Tags: python, gdal, grib

I have been working on this problem for a while now and have asked two seperate questions regarding it ([Counting events from a GRIB raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247962/counting-events-from-a-grib-raster), [ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge Python GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250016/valueerror-array-larger-than-output-file-or-offset-off-edge-python-gdal)), that have helped me tremendously. Still, the final solution eludes me. The code should iterate through a 24 images and compare each value to the conditions set in the loop, then write the number of instances the conditions were met into a GeoTIFF image. Despite being as sure as I can be, that this code should work as intended, I have still not been able to produce anything more than a GeoTIFF full of zeroes.

```
import gdal
import numpy
import osr
import os 

del_mapa = str(input('Vpiši pot do datotek v obliki "C:\\Mapa1\\Mapa2\\...\\Zadnja mapa": '))
os.chdir(del_mapa)

pix_vel = 1000
#Defines pixel size
ime_rez = str(input("Poimenuj datoteko z rezultati: ") + ".tif")
#User can provide a name for the output picture
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

vir_mere = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-0100.grb')
trans = vir_mere.GetGeoTransform()
geotrans0 = trans[0]
geotrans1 = trans[1]
geotrans3 = trans[3]
geotrans5 = trans[5]
#Extracts transformation data from one of the GRIBs
dst_ds = driver.Create(ime_rez, 401, 301, 1, gdal.GDT_CInt32)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([geotrans0, geotrans1, 0, geotrans3, 0, geotrans5])
#and pastes it directly into the newly created GeoTIFF
projInfo = vir_mere.GetProjection()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(vir_mere.GetProjectionRef())
dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

raster = numpy.zeros((301, 401), dtype=numpy.uint8)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)

def krog1(baza,novi):    
    x = 0
    while x < 25:
        baza = gdal.Open(ime_rez)
        if x < 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
            #This should open the next file in line
            if novi > 1 and novi < 12:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0

        elif x > 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
            if novi > 1 and novi < 12:
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0
        x += 1 
    return dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(baza)


dst_ds = None
```

Edit: The second half with additions and corrections as per the advice provided.

```
raster = numpy.zeros((301, 401), dtype=numpy.uint8)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
banda = vir_mere.GetRasterBand(1)
bandtip = gdal.GetDataTypeName(banda.DataType)

def krog1(baza,novi,bandtip):    
    vr_x = 0
    while x < 25:
        baza = gdal.Open(ime_rez)
        baza2 = baza.GetRasterBand(1)
        baza3 = baza2.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 301, 401).astype(numpy.CInt32)
        if x < 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % ('0' + str(x))
            #This should open the next file in line
            re_raster = novi.GetRasterBand(1)
            band_raster = re_raster.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 301, 401).astype(numpy.bandtip)
            #Reads the raster as an array and then follows the condition checking
            if band_raster > numpy.bandtip(1) and band_raster < numpy.bandtip(12):
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0
        elif x > 10:
            novi = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-%s00.grb') % (str(x))
            re_raster = novi.GetRasterBand(1)
            band_raster = re_raster.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 301, 401).astype(numpy.bandtip)
            if band_raster > numpy.bandtip(1) and band_raster < numpy.bandtip(12):
                baza = baza + 1
            else:
                baza = baza + 0
        vr_x += 1 
    return dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(baza)

dst_ds = None
```

Comment: Issue is because code only open rasters but it doesn't read datasets.

Comment: @xunilk is correct. You need to read the data, not just open the files. Look into the GDALDataset.GetRasterBand and RasterBand.ReadAsArray methods, or the gdal_array.DatasetReadAsArray function.

Comment: Found it, input it according to an example and still I can only get zeroes. I'll edit the question to show the additional code.

Comment: In the code you've provided above I don't see anywhere you're calling your function - looks like the script writes the array of zeros to the output and exits, which would be why your result is a tiff of zeros.

Comment: Should I then just put a line somwhere right before the dst_ds = None to say krog1(baza,novi,bandtip) or do I have to do more? @Ali

Comment: @peroman200 It's a bit more complex than that. If you add that specific line for the function call you'll get an error as 'baza' and 'novi' are defined in the function only. You therefore need to consider more about what arguments you need the function to take and also about what is going on inside the function. For instance, you're reading all the data at once and the check you are doing for numpy.bandtip will error too as bandtip is not a valid numpy attribute. You may find http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/ to be of help, particularly Weeks 4 & 5.

Comment: I have since noticed my errors in the header of the function. It should really be krog1(bandtip,ime_rez,dst_ds): because these are variables defined outside the function. I am however getting an error from the line baza2 = baza.GetRasterBand(1) that reads AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'.

Comment: PS. How can I read the the data type of a file and then import it in to a function if not with a variable? Do I just move it inside the function? Also, is there a problem perhapse in the fact that data type is different for the results file from the one in the read files? @Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've alluded to in my comments, you need to refine your function in terms of its arguments and outputs and then make sure you call it. That said, there are also some issues with the logic of your function and your raster access. I've rewritten your code as follows, with some comments for explanation:

```
import gdal
import numpy
import osr
import os
from osgeo import gdal_array # Used later to map data types

del_mapa = str(input('Vpiši pot do datotek v obliki "C:\\Mapa1\\Mapa2\\...\\Zadnja mapa": '))
os.chdir(del_mapa)

# User can provide a name for the output picture
ime_rez = str(input("Poimenuj datoteko z rezultati: ") + ".tif")

# Open your dataset to get the projection and transformation info
vir_mere = gdal.Open('inca_20140101-0100.grb')
# Get GetTransform - No need to break down into geotrans0 etc as the whole 
# object can be passed to SetGeoTransform later
trans = vir_mere.GetGeoTransform()
projInfo = vir_mere.GetProjection()

# Get band GDAL datatype and map to Numpy type
v_band = vir_mere.GetRasterBand(1)
gdal_band_type = v_band.DataType
np_band_type = gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(gdal_band_type) # Maps the GDAL data type to a Numpy type
# Close band and dataset
v_band = None
vir_mere = None

# Define function - won't do anything until it's called
def krog1(): 
    # Start by creating an array of zeros
    arr = numpy.zeros((301, 401), dtype=np_band_type)

    # Loop through the files in your current directory
    for f in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        # Open the file and read to array
        ds = gdal.Open(f)
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        # Read entire raster into array
        b_arr = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 401, 301).astype(np_band_type)
        # Loop over each cell in the array and, if between 1 and 12, add 1 to the corresponding value in arr
        for r in range(301):
            for c in range(401):
                if 1 < b_arr[r,c] < 12:
                    arr[r,c] += 1
    # return the updated array   
    return arr

# Call the above function storing the output in out_arr
out_arr = krog1()   

# Now create output and apply projection and transform info
dst_ds = driver.Create(ime_rez, 401, 301, 1, gdal.GDT_CInt32)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(trans)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(projInfo)
dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt()) 

# Write out_arr to band
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(out_arr)

# Flush to disk and close file
dst_ds.FlushCache()
dst_ds = None
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient way but should hopefully highlight the issues you were having and give you more of an understanding of raster processing with GDAL. Again, I recommend [this](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) resource.

I've included `gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(gdal_band_type)` here as this will give you the equivalent Numpy data type for your GDAL type which you can then use when creating or reading to arrays. Note that it requires the import of `gdal_array`.

As you are dealing with user input for your file paths you should check that a valid path has been provided. I think this is why you had that NoneType error when calling 'baza.GetRasterBand(1)' - if GDAL can't open the file it silently returns a NoneType.

---

**Update**

The call to `ReadAsArray` had the `win_xsize` and `win_ysize` arguments the wrong way round: `b_arr = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 301, 401).astype(np_band_type)` should have been `b_arr = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 401, 301).astype(np_band_type)`. Numpy shapes are always of the form (numrows,numcols) but the `ReadAsArray` function needs the order of numcols,numrows. I've updated the above.

Alternatively, if you don't pass any arguments the whole array will be read by default i.e. `b_arr = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np_band_type)`

Comment: It is amazing that you have rewriten the code, but unfortunately I still get the same NoneType error inside the: "for f in os.listdir(os.curdir):" on the line "band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)" I have tried different styled paths but while os.chdir() seems to work the GetRasterBand does not. @Ali

Comment: @peroman200 The loop cycles all files in the directory - if there are non-raster datasets in there, GDAL will return a NoneType when trying to open them. You can filter using, for example, if f.endswith('.grb'):... or similar to ensure only your intended files are opened.

Comment: I added the line you suggested (if f.endswith('.grb'):) and added an argument for the function that when called looks like this: krog1(np_band_type): because it was missing that external data. I am still getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype' in the: b_arr = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 301, 401).astype(np_band_type) line. I have removed all other files from the folder and left only .grb files I want it to process. @Ali

Comment: @peroman200 You don't need the np_band_type argument as it's defined outside the function and is global. As for the error, I had a couple of the arguments the wrong way round - I've update my answer with the change.